# Whats the advantage of SMACK over SE Linux?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-smack

Both offer policies which have to be enforced and are similar in operation. There is a concept of domains for both. But how does SMACK differ from SE linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name says it all: SMACK -> Simplified MAC kernel. The intention behind SMACK is to be much simpler and easier to understand than SELinux